# Odd langmap behavior with multi-key bindings

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

I'm getting some odd behavior from langmap.

With

```
set langmap=hjki;ihjk
```

`inoremap k u` works as expected,
`inoremap jk u` maps to `ji`,
`inoremap kik u` maps to `khi`.

When I say 'maps' I mean that's what I have to press to get the result.

It seems, for making keymaps, the langmap applies to every character but the first.
Setting `langremap` or `nolangremap` doesn't seem to have an effect.
I tried this with a clean init.vim, so there shouldn't be any other options or plugins affecting it.
I wanted to check here, to see if there's some langmap option I'm missing, before filing a bug report.

Using:

```
NVIM v0.3.1
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.0.5
```

Comment: Typically you need to enter a sequence of mapped characters within a certain time limit or they will just result in the literal characters. This is configured with either `'timeoutlen'` or `'ttimeoutlen'` depending on the values of `'timeout'` and `'ttimeout'`. The values for all these can be displayed with `:set to? ttimeout? tm? ttm?`. You don't happen to have a small value in there, do you? (See `:h 'timeout'` for explanation of all this.)

Comment: @BLayer `timeout` settings are default. Once I press `j`, vim waits for the next key for about a second.